# Why isn't header vertically centered, between navigation and footer, while using Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

`header` includes a `h1` element.

I added to `header`: `class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center min-vh-100"` but a vertical scrollbar appeared. I removed it by adding the `overflow-hidden` class in `body`, but the `header` is not vertically centered (it's a little below the x-axis center).

**Notice**: If I remove the navigation, the vertical centering works.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Βάκχος</span>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">Αρχική</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Ανέκδοτα</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Με βιλία</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<main>
  <header class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center min-vh-100">
    <h1 class="bg-primary">Όταν οι  έφτιαχναν μιμς, οι άλλοι έτρωγαν βελανίδια και κρέμονταν από τα δέντρα!</h1>
  </header>
</main>

<footer>
  <p>Footer</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: both `html` and `css` can't  *standalone*,so give us `css` as well

Comment: I don't have `CSS`. For the moment I'm using only HTML (with Bootstrap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be making the navbar to be positioned absolutely with width set to 100%.
This could be done by appending some Bootstrap classes to the nav.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark position-absolute w-100">
```

This makes the header centered vertically with respect to the screen.

Comment: Why was I getting this problem thought?

Comment: All elements are positioned as `static` by default. When changed to `absolute` position, the element would be removed from the regular document flow. More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).